# some marginnotes dont appear

Tags: tcolorbox

In the following example some of the marginnotes dont appear, even after the tcolorboxes. Which ones appear varies with the length of the tcolorbox. How can i make my marginnotes show up?

(My margins are set up this way because i plan to make heavy use of marginnotes)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.9cm,right=7.3cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4.8cm,marginparwidth=5.4cm,marginparsep=4.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
%\setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[]
\lipsum[2-5]
\marginnote[]{Test1.1}
\marginnote[Test1.2]{}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[]
\lipsum[2-2]
\marginnote[]{Test2.1}
\marginnote[Test2.2]{}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[]\lipsum[2-2]
\marginnote[]{Test2.1}
\marginnote[Test2.2]{}
\end{tcolorbox}

Some more Text\marginnote[]{Test3.1}\marginnote[Test3.2]{}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not really clear, what you expect. So I've added several examples to my answer. Please, next time specify which notes are missing in your opinion and where you expect them to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first optional argument and the mandatory argument of `\marginnote` are same as for `\marginpar`. The optional *<left>* argument is used, if the margin note is printed on the left margin (by default even pages in double-sided documents). The mandatory *<right>* argument is used, if the margin note is printed on the right margin (by default odd pages in double-sided document). The arguments cannot be used to move the used margin column from the left to the right or from the right to the left (see my last example, how to select another margin).

So if you use an empty *<left>* argument and the note is placed in the left margin, the empty note will be printed empty and therefore will be invisible. Same if you use an empty *<right>* argument and the output is at the right margin.

So everything is as expected.

Maybe you just want to use the mandatory argument only and remove the optional one. But in this case with two immediate following `\marginnote` the second one will overprint the first one:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.9cm,right=7.3cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4.8cm,marginparwidth=5.4cm,marginparsep=4.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
%\setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[]
  \lipsum[2-5]
  \marginnote{Test1.1}
  \marginnote{Test1.2}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[]
\lipsum[2-2]
\marginnote{Test2.1}
\marginnote{Test2.2}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[]\lipsum[2-2]
\marginnote{Test2.1}
\marginnote{Test2.2}
\end{tcolorbox}

Some more Text\marginnote{Test3.1}\marginnote{Test3.2}
\end{document}
```

[image: overprinting]

So maybe you also want a vertical offset for the second one:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.9cm,right=7.3cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4.8cm,marginparwidth=5.4cm,marginparsep=4.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
%\setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[]
  \lipsum[2-5]
  \marginnote{Test1.1}
  \marginnote{Test1.2}[\baselineskip]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[]
\lipsum[2-2]
\marginnote{Test2.1}
\marginnote{Test2.2}[\baselineskip]
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[]\lipsum[2-2]
\marginnote{Test2.1}
\marginnote{Test2.2}[\baselineskip]
\end{tcolorbox}

Some more Text\marginnote{Test3.1}\marginnote{Test3.2}[\baselineskip]
\end{document}
```

[image: vertical offset]

or a horizontal offset:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.9cm,right=7.3cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4.8cm,marginparwidth=5.4cm,marginparsep=4.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
%\setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[]
  \lipsum[2-5]
  \marginnote[Test1.1\hphantom{ Test1.2}]{Test1.1}%
  \marginnote[Test1.2]{\hphantom{Test1.1 }Test1.2}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[]
  \lipsum[2-2]
  \marginnote[Test2.1\hphantom{ Test2.2}]{Test2.1}%
  \marginnote[Test2.2]{\hphantom{Test2.1 }Test2.2}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[]\lipsum[2-2]
  \marginnote[Test2.1\hphantom{ Test2.2}]{Test2.1}%
  \marginnote[Test2.2]{\hphantom{Test2.1 }Test2.2}
\end{tcolorbox}

Some more Text%
\marginnote[Test3.1\hphantom{ Test3.2}]{Test3.1}%
\marginnote[Test3.2]{\hphantom{Test3.1 }Test3.2}

\end{document}
```

[image: horizontal offset]

But maybe you just want some of the notes on the left margin and some on the right margin. In this case you should use `\reversemarginpar` and `\normalmarginpar` to switch the margin used for the notes. But you don't need to use the optional argument, if the content of the note does not depend on the used margin:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.9cm,right=7.3cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4.8cm,marginparwidth=5.4cm,marginparsep=4.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
%\setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[]
\lipsum[2-5]
\marginnote{Test1.1}
\reversemarginpar
\marginnote{Test1.2}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[]
  \lipsum[2-2]
  \reversemarginpar
  \marginnote{Test2.1}
  \normalmarginpar
  \marginnote{Test2.2}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[]\lipsum[2-2]
  \reversemarginpar
  \marginnote{Test2.1}
  \normalmarginpar
  \marginnote{Test2.2}
\end{tcolorbox}

Some more Text\reversemarginpar\marginnote{Test3.1}\normalmarginpar\marginnote{Test3.2}
\end{document}
```

[image: both margins]

The optional argument is only needed, if the left and right content should differ as shown in the example with the horizontal offsets.

BTW: KOMA-Script also provides package `scrlayer-notecolumn` to be able to define several note columns, e.g., one at the left margin and one at the right margin, even with different width, and to allow to select the note column where the note should be printed. But AFAIK `scrlayer-notecolumn` is only a proof of concept and so I do not know, if it should be used for real life document.

Comment: Oh, So my Issue was to not understand that \marginnote[]{bla} behaves differently from \marginnote{bla}: If the page is a left-handed (in a book) the first one prints the empty-string on the inner margin... and bla in case of a right-handed page.
I originally expected all the notes to alteast show up somewhere, so thats why they "didn't" (they were empty).